# Fetch returns undefined - Express and React

Tags: reactjs, express, async-await, stripe-payments

I am following the stripe tutorial (from stripe) - But getting an undefined value returned from my server on a post request. Can you help figure out where I am messing up?

First, when the user hits the pay button it fires the 'joinClass()' function.

```
    const joinClass = async (youtubeId) => {

    const { data: clientSecret } = await fetch('/payment_intents', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({amount: costPerClass * 100})
    })

    console.log(clientSecret)
    //Returns Undefined

}
```

Here is the route on the server - It works but doesn't send back to the client_secret.

```
app.post('/payment_intents', async (req, res) => {
try {
    const { amount } = req.body
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount, 
        currency: "usd"
    })

    console.log(paymentIntent.client_secret)
    //Logs to key correctly.

    res.status(200).send(paymentIntent.client_secret);

} catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({statusCode: 500, message: 'error'})
}
```

})

Am I using the async/await incorrectly on the callback function in the server? I tried it a few different ways but it still returns undefined.

I destructured the name of the function (const { data: clientSecret } =.... just like they did in the video. Maybe this is the problem?

*Just tried the following - No Success

```
const joinClass = async (youtubeId) => {

    const data = await fetch('/payment_intents', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({amount: costPerClass * 100})
    })
    console.log(data)
    //Returns Response 200
    const dataResponse = await data.json()
    console.log(dataResponse)
    //Uncaught in promise

}
```

Comment: maybe try doing `const data = await fetch()` and `console.log(data)` as well as `console.log(data.json())`. what does it log?

Comment: Updated my question to try these two things - I get the response 200 from awaiting data. Awaiting data.json() returns uncaught in promise.

Comment: returns response 200 but does it return any `data` that you need? same with `dataResponse`, does it any data you need?

Comment: No - Neither returns the clientSecret key that I am sending form the server.

Comment: can u link to the tutorial you are following?

Comment: https://youtu.be/w1oLdAPyuok?t=1046  - Around 17 minutes and 26 seconds in, we start the 'Payment Intent' process.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214438/discussion-between-nick-mclean-and-deadcoder0904).

Answer (score 0):

The backend is sending back a simple text string in the `/payment_intents` response, so you would want to use the `response.text()` method when receiving the data in the frontend (rather than `response.json()`):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text

For example:

```
const response = await fetch("/payment_intents", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ amount: costPerClass * 100 }),
});

const clientSecret = await response.text();
```

The demo itself uses axios instead of fetch which has a bit of a different API: https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: Thanks for the help! Thats awesome to know. I ended up just using axios and it worked flawlessly. I didnt realize that axios did more than just make writing it a bit easier. Would you reccomend I change it back to the standard fetch library?

Comment: It's entirely up to you! Both work well, with the fetch api having the advantage of being a native web api. In general I find axios a bit easier to work with though, and there are some other advantages too: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/314#issuecomment-217346581